# Grohe Kitchen Faucet Membrane Replacement Instructions

Tags: faucet

I have a Grohe K4 kitchen faucet and need to replace the rubber membrane covering the on/off switch. I could not find any instructions and am wondering how to replace it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture would really help us.

Answer (score 1):

Try and pick the old one off with a fingernail, toothpick, or some other pointy bit of plastic. (Avoid metal, as you might scratch your finish.)

The new one should pop back in with simple finger pressure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Grohe makes a replacement membrane for the K4.  I had the same issue - button worked but membrane was torn.  I fixed it with Sugru!  It's moldable glue that turns to rubber when dried.   Put scotch tape over the old membrane so that it overlaps to the metal/faucet part.   Carefully use a razorblade or x-acto knife to cut around the edge of oval membrane - you are only cutting the tape, not the membrane.  Peel off the oval part of the tape so the you have created a stencil oval.  The old membrane is now visible.  Mix the Sugru (I mixed white with a little black to get the grey color) and carefully spread it over the existing membrane.  Use soapy hands to smooth out the Sugru.  Use toothpick to make the graphic dots to mark the spray area on the Sugru.  You can trace around the oval with the toothpick to mimic the old membrane.  Now carefully peel up the tape to take up the excess Sugru and you will have a clean oval Sugru membrane.   Let dry 24 hours and it will be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what model is what but if it looks like this, it will pop out as described above. When you get the new one, it will become very obvious how the dozen small tabs hold it in and when you install the new one, it just pops right in.
http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006WCIUCU

BTW...if you call Grohe (life time guarantee), they will send you one free...in fact they sent me 2!